# Generate alembic migration scripts from existing tables schema

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic

I have tables and it's schema. I neither have the database nor Sqlalchemy models. How do I generate alembic first version script with this information?

P.S. I could create a database with existing schema if that could be of help to get the alembic scripts.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [sqlcodegen](https://github.com/agronholm/sqlacodegen) to generate the sqlalchemy models, then create an empty database and use these models to create the initial alembic script.